# creating network groups / interconnection group between Primary Key and ID in R with recursive function

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  ID = c( "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2",
           "ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3",
           "ID1", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3"),
  
  Key = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 3, 9, 4,
           11, 15, 4, 17, 11, 15, 17, 4, 18)
)
```

Notice that "ID1" is assigned to keys 1, 3, 4, 11, and 17. So this keys are in a group1 
Hare "3" is the key for ID3 also. 
And ID3 has key "15" and "18". Thus "15" and "18" will also be in the same group as 1, 3, 4, 11, 17, 15, 18. The association of "ID"s to key is not unique. 
I want to find the all the groups and their keys. 
I tried to solved it in the following way:

```
dt_grp <- with(dt, split(Key, ID))

grp_fun <- function(x = list() ){
  
  n = length(x)
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    
    if (length( intersect( x[[i]], x[[n]] ) ) > 0) 
    {
      x[[i]] = append(x[[i]], x[[n]] ) 
      x <- x[ -n]
      x <- grp_fun(x)
    }
    else{
      return(x)
    }
    
  }
  
}


out <- grp_fun(dt_grp)
```

Something is wrong with my function hare.
I cannot figure out how to write a recursive function.
My understanding is Total number of groups will depend on number of interconnection between ID and Keys. Any help will be much appreciated. I will also appreciate any other functional methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  ID = c( "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2",
          "ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3",
          "ID1", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3"),
  
  Key = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 3, 9, 4,
          11, 15, 4, 17, 11, 15, 17, 4, 18)
)

t <- table(dt$ID,dt$Key)

new_groups <- list()

for (i in rownames(t)) {
  row_values <- as.integer(names(t[i,])[t[i,]>0])
  #row_values <- as.integer(rep(names(t[i,])[t[i,]>0],t[i,t[i,]>0])) # see: COMMENT #1

  if(length(new_groups)==0) { # If list is empty
    new_groups[[1]] <- row_values # Add first key values to group 1
  } else {
    create_new_group <- TRUE # By default parameter is set to TRUE
    for(list_item in seq_len(length(new_groups))) {
      if(max(row_values %in% new_groups[[list_item]])==1) { # If key values (some or all) exist in current group
        
        new_groups[[list_item]] <- unique(c(new_groups[[list_item]], row_values)) # Add key values to current group
        #new_groups[[list_item]] <- append(new_groups[[list_item]], row_values) # see: COMMENT #1
        create_new_group <- FALSE
      } 
    }
    
    # Create new group with row_values
    if(create_new_group) {
      new_groups[[length(new_groups)+1]] <- row_values
    }
  }
}

# COMMENT #1 - use this instead of prev. row if you want to collect non-unique key values
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the split function you will get a grouping returned as a list:

```
with(dt, split(Key, ID))
#--output follows
$ID1
[1]  1  1  1  3  4  4 11 17

$ID2
[1]  2  2  8  9 11 15  4

$ID3
[1]  3 15 18

$ID4
[1] 5

$ID5
[1]  7 17
```

So assign to a symbol:

```
dt_grps <- with(dt, split(Key, ID))
# And extract from that list with "[["
dt_grps[['ID5']]
#----------
[1]  7 17
```

And total number of groups will just be `length(dt_grps)`.

If you wnated to "split" into separate dataframes, tehn there is also a function for that:

```
split(dt, dt$ID) # returns a list of dataframes with variable row count.
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not give my answer. Hare all the groups are based on "ID"s. For example, "ID5" has key 7, 17. Notice that 17 is also a key for "ID1". So  1, 3, 4, 11, 17 should be in the same group. May be my question was not explicit. I edited it a bit. Hope it is explicit enough.

Comment: What you should have done is emphasize the fact that the association of ID's to values was not unique.